To Find a Word Beginning with B: Adjective, in the Shape of a Grape
Probably spelled like biutyrial (only a reference), not included in dictionaries. But I remembered I have seen an article on merriam-webster.com about different shapes and funny insults. There are some words I could recollect from that page:
muskcod: a man who wears a lot of perfume
naliform: in the shape of an ass. Perhaps that grape B-word showed up in in this paragraph.
And there is an anology when the page  showed the vault adjective is vaulted, probably after the B-word.
I cannot find synonyms for grapelike beginning with B in several thesauruses.

I’m voting to close this question because looking up 'grapelike' in a thesaurus (eg [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com › browse › grapelike)) gives 'botryose', defined as 'having the form of a cluster of grapes'. As far as I know, there is no word (except perhaps 'ovoid') meaning 'shaped like a grape'.

@EdwinAshworth but ovoid means "shaped like an egg"!

@phoog 'Vitis vinifera ... The fruit is a berry, known as a grape, that is ovoid or globular, dark blue or greenish, usually 2-locular with 5 seeds' [Wikipedia]

@EdwinAshworth - As a parallel to ovoid I'd propose uvoid (where the Latin for egg is ova, the Latin for grape is uva). It's where we get the word uvula

@Jim Mack Suggesting D-I-Y coinings is explicitly off-topic on ELU.

Botryoidal means having the form of a bunch of grapes (apparently from Latin botrus and/or Greek βότρυς, meaning grape or bunch of grapes).

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/botryoidal
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/botryoidal

You may have had trouble finding the M-W page because the second word is natiform rather than naliform (from Latin natis, meaning rump or buttocks).  It is Rare and Amusing Insults, Volume 3.  In discussing natiform, it mentions, and links to the definitions of, alligatoroid, botryoidal, and vaulty.  They must be very rare indeed, as my spell checker and autocorrect are both unaware of them, as they are of natiform.

The full OED definition for musk-cod is 2. 1600–61 A heavily perfumed gentleman; a fop. Often as a derogatory form of address. With cited usages by both Ben Jonson and Shakespeare, so that one wasn't hard to find, even though apparently it vanished after 1661 (until its recent resurrection on the Internet! :)

I certainly can't explain the downvote. I knew there would be a Latin or Ancient Greek term for "like a bunch of grapes", but I didn't know it off the top of my head, so I was impressed that you had it. Perhaps the downvoter thinks the target word should be the shape of a single grape. But that's silly, because there's nothing unusual about grape-shape (at least ovoid = egg-shaped implies one end more pointy than the other). Grapes are just oblate spheroids, same as lots of things.

@FumbleFingers my primary strategy was to look at the B section of the English "shapes" category in Wiktionary, but a couple of entries that should be there aren't.  I found enough to identify the root (with a brief diversion toward the Greek word for "butter") and then started typing likely words into dictionary search boxes.  The breakthrough was typing botyr.... instead of butyr..., whereupon I got botyroidal as a misspelling of butryoidal.

Now I think on it, some (small) varieties of grapes are near-perfect spheres. But the OP can't possibly be thinking of those.
